# Assumption of square integrability with respect to time for initial condition $x_0$.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

I am working through some proofs related to differential equations and stochastic differential equations related to existence of solutions.

Consider a SDE

$$ 
dX_t = f(t,X_t)dt + dW_t
$$

The following assumption I am unclear on

Assumption:

There exists $x_0 \in E$ such that $f(t,x_0) \in L^2[0,T]$ for all $0 < T <\infty$.

Why is this important for it to be integrable for the initial condition and not for all possible $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that f is Lipschitz also, which is the common condition for existence/uniqueness as in Shreve-Karatzas 5.2/2.9 theorem
[image]

Well because then you can obtain it for general x too

$$\int_{0}^{T}f^{2}(t,x)dt\leq \int_{0}^{T}c|x-x_{0}|^{2}dt+\int_{0}^{T}f^{2}(t,x_{0})dt<\infty,$$

where we used

$$|f(t,x)|^{2}=|f(t,x)-f(t,x_{0})+f(t,x_{0})|^{2}\leq |f(t,x)-f(t,x_{0})|^{2}+|f(t,x_{0})|^{2}.$$

Comment: oh sheesh, I was way over-thinking it. Thank you, that's so clear.